# Calculating azimuth of nearest features

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm calculating nearest points between two sf objects (point). I need to get the nearest hub's name, the distance and the azimut direction. At this moment I got the name and the distance but I can't figure it out how to get the direction between ben's points and each nearest hub.

```
library(sf)

#create the point layers
x_hub <- c(483049,482685)
y_hub <- c(4691026,4686387)
x_origin <- c(489597,489935,479537,476802,486356)
y_origin <- c(4696493,4695278,4692577,4684002,4690383)
p1 <- st_point(c(x_hub[1],y_hub[1]))
p2 <- st_point(c(x_hub[2],y_hub[2]))
p3 <- st_point(c(x_origin[1],y_origin[1]))
p4 <- st_point(c(x_origin[2],y_origin[2]))
p5 <- st_point(c(x_origin[3],y_origin[3]))
p6 <- st_point(c(x_origin[4],y_origin[4]))
p7 <- st_point(c(x_origin[5],y_origin[5]))
hub <- st_sfc(p1,p2, crs = 25831)
atr_hub <- data.frame(id= c(1,2))
hub <- st_sf(atr_hub, geometry = hub)
origin <- st_sfc(p3,p4,p5,p6,p7, crs=25831)
atr_origin <- data.frame(id= c(1:5))
origin <- st_sf(atr_origin, geometry = origin)


#find the hub name and save in origin
hubname <- st_nearest_feature(origin,hub)
origin$hubname <- hubname

#distance matrix between origin and hub
dist_matrix <- st_distance(origin,hub, by_element=FALSE)

#get the minimum value in each row and save in origin
dist <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(dist_matrix)){
  print(i)
  dist[i] <- min(dist_matrix[i,])
}
origin$dist <- dist
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, your example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because only you have access to your `.shp` files. Can you modify your post with a reproducible example?

Comment: I edited to use some points of my data. Now it is reproducible. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the modified script below to get the (planar) azimuth to nearest point, using package `nngeo`. The development version needs to be installed from GitHub for this to work:

```r
remotes::install_github("michaeldorman/nngeo")
```

The script:

```r
library(sf)
library(nngeo)

#create the point layers
x_hub <- c(483049,482685)
y_hub <- c(4691026,4686387)
x_origin <- c(489597,489935,479537,476802,486356)
y_origin <- c(4696493,4695278,4692577,4684002,4690383)
p1 <- st_point(c(x_hub[1],y_hub[1]))
p2 <- st_point(c(x_hub[2],y_hub[2]))
p3 <- st_point(c(x_origin[1],y_origin[1]))
p4 <- st_point(c(x_origin[2],y_origin[2]))
p5 <- st_point(c(x_origin[3],y_origin[3]))
p6 <- st_point(c(x_origin[4],y_origin[4]))
p7 <- st_point(c(x_origin[5],y_origin[5]))
hub <- st_sfc(p1,p2, crs = 25831)
atr_hub <- data.frame(id= c(1,2))
hub <- st_sf(atr_hub, geometry = hub)
origin <- st_sfc(p3,p4,p5,p6,p7, crs=25831)
atr_origin <- data.frame(id= c(1:5))
origin <- st_sf(atr_origin, geometry = origin)

#find the hub name and save in origin
hubname <- st_nearest_feature(origin,hub)
origin$hubname <- hubname

##############

# Find distances and azimuths
origin$dist = st_distance(origin, hub[hubname, ], by_element = TRUE)
origin$az = st_azimuth(origin, hub[hubname, ])

# Plot
plot(st_union(st_geometry(origin), st_geometry(hub)), col = NA)
plot(st_geometry(origin), col = "grey", add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(hub), col = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(st_connect(origin, hub), col = "grey", add = TRUE)
text(st_coordinates(origin), as.character(round(origin$az)))
```

And here is the plot produced by the last part of the script, showing the direction towards the nearest point along with the azimuth:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Also for making my code more efficient and classy. I'm a self-learner and I'm aware that I wrote plenty of useless lines. Step by step.